# How can I change a class on scroll with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm working in a little project and here I need to make a menu fixed when scroll, I made a research and I find a lot of information about it, but I can't make it work! :( I have this:

```
<nav id="change" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>INICIO</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>SERVICIOS</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>EQUIPO</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>SKILLS</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>


<style>
  .menu {
   position: fixed;
   margin-left: 15%;
   margin-top: 15px;
   width: 70%;
   background-image: url('../imagenes/logo2.png');
   background-size: 40px;
   background-position: 3% calc(middle + 5px);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   z-index: 100;
  }

.menuF {
   position: fixed;
   margin-top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   background-image: url('../imagenes/logo2.png');
   background-size: 40px;
   background-position: 3% calc(middle + 5px);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   z-index: 100;
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var pixelnum= 50;
        $(window).scroll(function() {    
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll > pixelnum) {
                $('#change').removeClass('menu').addClass('menuF');
            } else {
                $('#change').removeClass("menuF").addClass('menu');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

all my script is into a script tag into the same HTML document, can somebody tell me why it isn't working?
and how to solve this?

I'm very very new in jQuery and javascript but I have some knowledge with C++ so I hope this help.

Sorry my english level
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail exactly what behavior you want?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/

Comment: So, what's not working? Your fiddle works for me using Chrome.

Comment: Thats not my code, it's just what I want to achieve, the Fiddle below works fine, but I can't make it work into my webpage, I feel really bad :( I don't know what is wrong, if isn't the javascript and the CSS (I've try Seamus answer) and it still not working, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your CSS, not in your javascript. Compare this to what you are doing, and see if it fixes your problem:

```js
$(function() {
    var pixelnum= 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        
        if (scroll > pixelnum) {
            $('#change').removeClass('menu').addClass('menuF');
        } else {
            $('#change').removeClass("menuF").addClass('menu');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-image: url('../imagenes/logo2.png');
    background-size: 40px;
    background-position: 3% calc(middle + 5px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
}
.menuF {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-image: url('../imagenes/logo2.png');
    background-size: 40px;
    background-position: 3% calc(middle + 5px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="change" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>INICIO</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>SERVICIOS</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>EQUIPO</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>SKILLS</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<p>You've reached the bottom.</p>
```

Comment: Nope, I think there is something more :/ the code above just modify the style, this still not working, I'm going to read my html document, to see if I'm losing something, maybe an open tag or something like that... thanks!

Comment: I feel really stupid, yes, your answer is the correct, but not because the css, well not at all, I just add
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
to the head and now everything is working, thanks a lot, really thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First put your Jquery in < script > tag.

and then add this to CSS

```
      .menuF{
       postion:fixed;
       top:0;
       z-index: 1000;
       display:block;
      }
```